# Insert hexadecimal to mysql via JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to insert to my database a hexadecimal value via JAVA, but, it isn't working.

I **NEED** to use this way:

```
CALL adduser('admin',0xf6fdffe48c908deb0f4c3bd36c032e72, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '0xf6fdffe48c908deb0f4c3bd36c032e72')
```

Note, the second variable is without simple quotes, but how do I do the same thing with JAVA?

Java Code:

```
String login = request.getParameter("login");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String result = "";

        String login_password = login + password;

        MessageDigest m;
        try {
            m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            m.update(login_password.getBytes());
            BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, m.digest());
            result = hash.toString(16);
            while (result.length() < 32) { // 40 for SHA-1
                result = "0" + result;
            }
            result = "0x" + result;

            System.out.println("Result: " + result);
            

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.13:3306/dbo", "root", "root");

            CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call adduser(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

            cstmt.setString(1, login);
            cstmt.setString(2, result);
            
            cstmt.setString(3, "0");
            cstmt.setString(4, "0");
            cstmt.setString(5, "0");
            cstmt.setString(6, "0");
            cstmt.setString(7, "0");
            cstmt.setString(8, "0");
            cstmt.setString(9, "0");
            cstmt.setString(10, "0");
            cstmt.setString(11, "0");
            cstmt.setString(12, "0");
            cstmt.setString(13, "0");
            cstmt.setString(14, "0");
            cstmt.setString(15, "0");
            cstmt.setString(16, "0");
            cstmt.setString(17, result);

            cstmt.executeUpdate();
            cstmt.close();
```

The hexadecimal is just fine... No need to bother with...

My guess is this line    `cstmt.setString(2, result);` is not String type. But what should I use?

MYSQL
Right:
[image]

JAVA
Wrong:
[image]

Comment: Is the `password` column of type `BLOB`?

Comment: Get rid of `result`. Capture the `byte[]` returned by `m.digest()`. Call `cstmt.setBytes(2, bytes);`

Comment: @JanezKuhar it is varchar(64) utf8_general_ci

Comment: @Andreas I need it to be digested and than tranformed into a hexadecimal as 0xf6fdffe48c908deb0f4c3bd36c032e72.
I've tried with PHP and it's working fine...

here is the example:
```$connection = mysqli_connect("pwdbo", "root", "root", "dbo", "3306");```
```$Login = "admin";```
```$Pass = "admin";```
```$Salt = $Login . $Pass;```
```$Salt = md5($Salt);```
```$Salt = "0x" . $Salt;```
```mysqli_query($connection, "CALL adduser('$Login',$Salt, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '$Salt')");```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `result`. Capture the `byte[]` returned by `m.digest()`. Call `cstmt.setBytes(2, bytes);`

```java
byte[] digestBytes;
try {
    MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    digestBytes = m.digest(login_password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    throw new AssertionError("MD5 is missing", e);
}

try (
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.13:3306/dbo", "root", "root");
    CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call adduser(?,?,'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',?)}");
) {
    cstmt.setString(1, login);
    cstmt.setBytes(2, digestBytes);
    cstmt.setBytes(3, digestBytes);
    cstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

If the last parameter is a `varchar`, then use:

```java
    cstmt.setString(3, "0x" + toHexString(digestBytes));
```

where `toHexString()` is a helper method, e.g. using `BigInteger` to format the bytes as a hex string.

Comment: Work like a charm!
Thanks!